# Express - socket.io - reading session

Tags: session, node.js, socket.io

I use Express and socket.io.

When you create a session with the express - post. Click the button and using Ajax and the POST method (login), I save a session.

```
 app.post('/login', function(req, res){
         req.session.loginid = req.body.lgnid;
    });
```

In socket.io it can not read.

My source code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app); 
var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;
var sessionStore = new MemoryStore();
var parseCookie = require('connect').utils.parseCookie;
var Session = require('connect').middleware.session.Session;
var stylus = require('stylus');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({store: sessionStore
        , secret: 'secret'
        , key: 'express.sid'}));

  app.use(stylus.middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public', compile: compile }))
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.set('views', __dirname);

 // disable layout
  app.set("view options", {layout: false});

  // make a custom html template
  app.register('.html', {
    compile: function(str, options){
      return function(locals){
        return str;
      };
    }
  });

  function compile (str, path) {
    return stylus(str)
      .set('filename', path)
      .use(nib());
  };

var Session = require('connect').middleware.session.Session;
sio.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
    if (data.headers.cookie) {
        data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
        data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];
        // save the session store to the data object 
        // (as required by the Session constructor)
        data.sessionStore = sessionStore;
        sessionStore.get(data.sessionID, function (err, session) {
            if (err || !session) {
                accept('Error', false);
            } else {
                // create a session object, passing data as request and our
                // just acquired session data
                data.session = new Session(data, session);
                accept(null, true);
            }
        });
    } else {
       return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
});
```

**How to load and save data from sessionStore?**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 
    var hs = socket.handshake;
    console.log('Session : ' + hs.session.loginid + '); //Session : undefined

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recommended way to achieve this actually (at least in my experience) is to forgo the `sessionStore.get` function and go for `sessionStore.load` instead - the difference is that with load the callback is given a session instance instead of having to create one yourself. The difference is simply taking your snippet:

```
sessionStore.get(data.sessionID, function (err, session) {
    if (err || !session) {
        accept('Error', false);
    } else {
        // create a session object, passing data as request and our
        // just acquired session data
        data.session = new Session(data, session);
        accept(null, true);
    }
});
```

And changing it to:

```
sessionStore.load(data.sessionID, function(err, session) {
  if (err || !session) {
    accept("Error", false);
  } else {
    data.session = session;
    accept(null, true);
  }
});
```

And from there, you should be able to access the session as you attempt, such as `socket.handshake.session`, however when dealing with the session if you make changes in a socket event you have to manually save the session yourself. If you add/remove things you must: `session.save([callback])`.

I realize this isn't much of an answer since I'm telling you to do roughly what you already are but this is working for me right now with Express `2.5.8` and Socket.IO `0.9.6`.